# Gerar chave sequencial com firebase

Tags: android, firebase, app, realtime-database

Bom dia !
Estou trabalhando em um app que salva algumas atividades de usuários e estou com um problema para salvar essas atividades gerando numeros sequenciais, eis o ambiente: eu tenho o usuario A logado, ele irá criar uma nova atividade e ao salvar ela no nó ATIVIDADES ela recebe o numero id 1, depois o usuario B salva uma outra atividade em outro celular que receberá o id 2, depois o usuario A salva uma nova agora com o id 3... e assim sucessivamente...
Desde já agradeço!

Comment: então, faça o seguinte, recolha a informação desejada do firebase caso ela aja, no caso é o id do tipo inteiro, e acrescente 1 toda vez que for adicionar algo novo.

Comment: Você pode guardar a informação do id da última atividade como o @Matheus falou e utilizar set no lugar do push para salvar os dados. Com o set o seu path já deve incluir o id que vai ser utilizado. Ex: `fb.ref('atividades/${lastId+1}/').set({atividade});`

Answer (score -1):

Use o método `push()` ele faz na sequência seus dados

```
database.child("dados").push().setValue(objeto);
```